# flask bring css into html files

Tags: python, html, css, flask, html-email

I have some `html` and `css` files which are linked in the head section of my code. I am working on sending one specific html file from flask via email. The problem is that I need the css to be included in the html file, otherwise it does not show up correctly. Is there a way to do this with flask/python dynamically?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can zip HTML file and needed CSS files and then send

Comment: Better is to use inline styling.

Comment: Yup; read the HTML file; replace the <link rel=stylesheet> links by <style>..</style> with the content of the css files.

Comment: Why do people downvote for no reason? This is a valid question.

Comment: @darksky I wasn't the downvoter, but it might be because this question looks like a "gimme teh codez" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need this snippet from `flask` called `get_resource_as_string` http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/77/

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_resource_as_string(name, charset='utf-8'):
    with app.open_resource(name) as f:
        return f.read().decode(charset)

app.jinja_env.globals['get_resource_as_string'] = get_resource_as_string
```

And then you can include your stylesheet in the page like so

```
<style type=text/css>{{ get_resource_as_string('static/styles.css') }}</style>
```

This will write the css file directly into the document, eliminating the need for a separate CSS file.